# Calculating revolutions per minute in Python from an Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to calculate rpm's in python via a reed switch from the arduino.
i cant seem to get it right. can some one please help me get the code right.
my results are not consistent.

my problem is I'm trying to count the revolution per minute but I'm having issues with the minute part. the revolution counter works OK every time the reed switch is passed the count increases 1,2,3,4,5,6(etc). but, the rpm part witch is rev / ((time.time() - t)/60) gives me a result that keeps increases the value does not increase or decrease fast enough according to the speed of the revolution. so when when the reed switch is passed at 30 rev per minute it should reed out 30 RPM; when when the reed switch is passed at 90 rev per minute it should reed out 90 RPM. i know that i need to get a count of revolution for every minute, i guess its the ever minute part that i having a hard time programing.

thanks for helping me out this has been bothering me for months now.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
t = time.time()
a = ser.read()

rev = 0

while  (a == ser.read()):


    rev += 1
    print rev / ((time.time() - t)/60)
```

New problem, now I'm trying to add two reed switches. i can get both to work separately, but when i go to pass the second reed switch i get script terminated. i now why I'm getting the script termination( one if true other is false terminate), but I'm not sure how to code it properly. the b'1' and b'2' is what is coming in from the arduino

my goal is to get both reeds to read at the same time.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
a = ser.read()
t0 = time.time()


while(a == ser.read()):

    if a == b'2':
        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            print(1 / ((t1-t0)/60))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        t0 = t1
    if a == b'1':
        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            print(1 / ((t1-t0)/60))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        t0 = t1
```

my none working code so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do. if i could somehow break out the b'1' and b'2'. down below in the font object part you will see were m and r will need to go

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
t0 = time.time()

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('MPH!')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (148, 228, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


while True:
    a = ser.read()

    if a == b'2':

        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            rpmm = (1 / ((t1-t0)/60))
            m = str((7.065 *rpmm * 60)/5280).strip("\n,\r")

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        t0 = t1
    if a == b'1':
        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            r = str((1 / ((t1-t0)/60))).strip("\n,\r")


        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        t0 = t1



    fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('digitaldream', 40)
    textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render('MPH:'+m, True, BLUE, BLACK)
    textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
    textRectObj.center = (200, 150)

    fontObj2 = pygame.font.SysFont('digitaldream', 40)
    textSurfaceObj2 = fontObj2.render('RPM:'+r, True, BLUE, BLACK)
    textRectObj2 = textSurfaceObj2.get_rect()
    textRectObj2.center = (200, 200)




    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, your code will output the *average* RPM since the reading started. If `ser.read()` returns one time for every rotation, you can do something like this to get the instantaneous rotation speed:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
a = ser.read()
t0 = time.time()

while(a == ser.read()):
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        print(1 / ((t1-t0)/60))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
    t0 = t1
```

If you take a look at your new code, you should realize that the variable `a` is not assigned any new value during the while loop. You only check if `ser.read()` is equal to the value it had before you entered the for loop. This means that if `ser.read()` takes another value than what it had prior to entering the while loop, the statement `a == ser.read()` will be `False`.

This code will work for both values of ser.read().

```
import serial
import time


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
t0 = time.time()

while True:
    a = ser.read()
    if a == b'2' or a == b'1':
        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            print(1 / ((t1-t0)/60))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        t0 = t1
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get a division by zero if your first read is too fast.