# Convert revolutions of a gearbox to RPM in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotics

I'm building a robot in Python3. I have an engine that reports total number of revolutions of its gearbox between longer lasting complete halts:

```
import ftrobopy    
Motor1 = Robo.motor(1)
Motor1.getCurrentDistance()
```

so after a halt this value will start at 0 and then go up to whatever (its quickly in six figures) until it resets at some point.

Now I want to run some code rpm dependant. IE shift into a higher gear when RPM exceeds a certain value. So I need to find a way to convert what the Motor reports as revolutions to revolutions per time interval.

I need something that correlates well with short term changes in rpm, reflecting whats happening in the last couple of seconds. I'm not sure how to implement this.

I have tried to implement this solution:

[Calculating revolutions per minute in Python from an Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640579/calculating-revolutions-per-minute-in-python-from-an-arduino)

removing the serial parts and working with Motor1.getCurrentDistance() for = a.

But it doesn't seem to be doing at all what I'm looking for. If you could give me any pointers this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT2: this is the current state of things:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import ftrobopy
import threading


txt=ftrobopy.ftrobopy('auto')

joystick1 = txt.joystick(0,1,1)
joystick2 = txt.joystick(1,1,1)
Motor1 = txt.motor(1)
Motor1.setDistance(0)
txt.updateWait()

def infiniteloop1():  # this controls the motor via a remote
    while True:
        Motor1.setSpeed(joystick1.leftright() * 512)


def infiniteloop2():  # this is for the rpm meter
    while True:
        curRev = Motor1.getCurrentDistance()
        t0 = time.time()
        lastRev = 0

        while (curRev == Motor1.getCurrentDistance()):
            t1 = time.time()
            try:
                rpm = (curRev - lastRev / ((t1 - t0) / 4320))
                print("RPM: " + "%.1f" % rpm)
                print("RevsTotal: " + str(Motor1.getCurrentDistance()))
                time.sleep(5)
                txt.updateWait()

            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass
            t0 = t1
            lastRev = curRev
            txt.updateWait()






thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop2)
thread2.start()
```

When I execute this it will start with RPM and TotalRev = 0 and then RPM and TotalRev remain the same value (100..200..).  When I stop the motor TotalRev stays at last value and RPM becomes a negative number that will slowly become bigger over time. I must have messed up somewhere?

Comment: [For legal reasons, Stack Overflow doesn't accept users under 13.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/why-cant-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old-and-is-there-any-way-i)

Comment: Thanks. I have remedied that problem and an adult is using this site with me as per the instructions in that link.

Comment: The algorithm in the other question you provided seems to be valid for your case as well. Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have edited what I got so far into the OP. Its basically showing just random numbers.

Comment: I have only found documentation for the `ftrobopy` module in German (https://github.com/ftrobopy/ftrobopy/blob/master/manual.pdf) - is there any English documentation? (I can read German, most people here probably can't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't calculate the number of revolutions performed by the motor, only the time elapsed

```
rpm = (1 / ((t1 - t0) / 60))
```

You need to need to include a variable to store the last number of revolutions, then subtract that number from the current number of revolutions.

```
def infiniteloop2():  # this is for the rpm meter
    while True:
        Motor1 = txt.motor(1)
        a = Motor1.getCurrentDistance()
        t0 = time.time()
        lastRev = 0

        while (curRev == Motor1.getCurrentDistance()):
            t1 = time.time()
            try:
                rpm = (curRev - lastRev / ((t1 - t0) / 60))
                print("RPM: " + "%.1f" % rpm)

            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass
            time.sleep(2)
            t0 = t1
            lastRev = curRev
```

Comment: Side note: The documentation says that the "distance" is measured in 72 steps per revolution since the last `setCurrentDistance()` command. I presume that the motor is a stepper motor. Without calling `setCurrentDistance()`, any call to `getCurrentDistance()` seems to be useless.

Comment: Jørgen R: Thanks for helping out! I have implemented the code and added a second print for TotalRevs for debugging. It seems that totalRev and RPM are showing the same numbers now.

Tomalak: thanks! I have edited the code to initially set Motor1.setDistance(0) so that I get a consecutive count, if I understand you correctly that should do the trick.

Comment: Its working perfectly now. Thanks so much Jørgen R!!! Only thing i changed was place the division by 60 into a separate line as it would not work for some reason otherwise.

Comment: @Grindtime remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: @Jørgen R - Just did! Thanks for reminding me. Still learning the ins and outs of this site.